# What part of a HTTP header gets parsed my rewrite engines?

Tags: http, header, http-headers, url-rewriting

Given the below header:

```
GET /resources/css/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer: http://site.com/
```

What part of the header gets parsed by rewrite engines? (I mostly concern about Nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET part, that is, `/resources/css/jquery-ui.css` in your example.